# Android qemu emulator tool cross compiled for arm64 not able to boot emulator

Tags: android, cross-compiling, emulation, qemu, arm64

I have a mac studio machine with an m1 cpu running Ubuntu. I would like to run arm android emulators on it but as of yet I have been unable to do so. I have tried both arm and x86 emulator images and neither have worked.

I have cross compiled the emulator tool using the steps show at: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#emulator_for_arm64_hosts on my x86 machine and have been able to successfully compile the emulator tool for arm64.

However when I run any avd with this tool it crashes with a seg-fault at boot. I am running it using the following options:
`emulator -log-detailed -debug all -no-window -verbose -avd YetAnotherTestAvd`

And I get the output (cut to the failure):

```
15:17:44.925156 281473108601600 INFO    Quickboot.cpp:367                  | Loading snapshot 'default_boot'...
15:17:44.925495 281473108601600 WARNING qemu-vm-operations-impl.cpp:457    | Device 'encrypt' does not have the requested snapshot 'default_boot'
15:17:44.925507 281473108601600 DEBUG   qemu-vm-operations-impl.cpp:487    | Snapshot load vm result -2 success 1
15:17:44.925513 281473108601600 WARNING Quickboot.cpp:387                  | Failed to load snapshot 'default_boot'
15:17:44.925519 281473108601600 INFO    window-agent-headless-impl.cpp:81  | Cold boot based on user configuration
15:17:44.925524 281473108601600 DEBUG   NullMetricsReporter.cpp:31         | (metrics::reportConditional) ignoring
15:17:44.925534 281473108601600 WARNING Quickboot.cpp:454                  | Cold boot based on user configuration
15:17:44.925692 281473108601600 DEBUG   async-socket-connector.c:201       | Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 111 -> Connection refused
15:17:44.925703 281473108601600 DEBUG   async-socket-connector.c:215       | ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 21
15:17:45.216933 281473247668992 DEBUG   gps.cpp:52                         | sending '$GPGGA,141745,3914.2353,N,12309.0019,W,1,6,,0.0,M,0.,M,,,*47'
15:17:45.216992 281473247668992 DEBUG   gps.cpp:52                         | sending '$GPRMC,141745,A,3914.2353,N,12309.0019,W,0.00,0.00,301023,0.0,W*47'
15:17:45.590834 281473091595008 INFO    os_utils.cc:86                     | Unable to find netsim ini file: /run/user/1001/netsim.ini
15:17:45.590914 281473091595008 ERROR   packet_streamer_client.cc:116      | Starting netsim since the process died
15:17:45.590977 281473091595008 ERROR   packet_streamer_client.cc:85       | Netsimd launch command:
15:17:45.591000 281473091595008 ERROR   packet_streamer_client.cc:86       | 
15:17:45.597172 281473091595008 ERROR   Command_Posix.cpp:312              | Unable to spawn process  due to:, No such file or directory
15:17:45.597207 281473091595008 ERROR   packet_streamer_client.cc:91       | Running netsimd as pid: 1503705264.
15:17:45.597241 281473091595008 ERROR   packet_streamer_client.cc:120      | Retry connecting to netsim in 2 second.
15:17:46.217083 281473247668992 DEBUG   gps.cpp:52                         | sending '$GPGGA,141746,3914.2353,N,12309.0019,W,1,6,,0.0,M,0.,M,,,*47'
15:17:46.217148 281473247668992 DEBUG   gps.cpp:52                         | sending '$GPRMC,141746,A,3914.2353,N,12309.0019,W,0.00,0.00,301023,0.0,W*47'
15:17:47.084081 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud_service.cpp:81       | qemud_service_connect_client: registered client channel -1 for 'boot-properties' service
15:17:47.084368 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud.cpp:194              | _qemudPipe_sendBuffers: 0004
15:17:47.084417 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud.cpp:194              | _qemudPipe_sendBuffers: list
15:17:47.084430 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud_client.cpp:96        | _qemud_pipe_send: len= 26 'ro.opengles.version=196608'
15:17:47.084438 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud.cpp:273              | _qemudPipe_recvBuffers: -> 30 (of 1024)
15:17:47.084449 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud_client.cpp:96        | _qemud_pipe_send: len= 24 'qemu.sf.fake_camera=back'
15:17:47.084460 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud.cpp:273              | _qemudPipe_recvBuffers: -> 28 (of 1024)
15:17:47.084468 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud_client.cpp:96        | _qemud_pipe_send: len= 23 'dalvik.vm.heapsize=512m'
15:17:47.084479 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud.cpp:273              | _qemudPipe_recvBuffers: -> 27 (of 1024)
15:17:47.084488 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud_client.cpp:96        | _qemud_pipe_send: len= 18 'qemu.hw.mainkeys=1'
15:17:47.084499 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud.cpp:273              | _qemudPipe_recvBuffers: -> 22 (of 1024)
15:17:47.084507 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud_client.cpp:96        | _qemud_pipe_send: len= 23 'qemu.sf.lcd_density=160'
15:17:47.084518 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud.cpp:273              | _qemudPipe_recvBuffers: -> 27 (of 1024)
15:17:47.084526 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud_client.cpp:96        | _qemud_pipe_send: len= 24 'net.wifi_mac_prefix=5554'
15:17:47.084536 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud.cpp:273              | _qemudPipe_recvBuffers: -> 28 (of 1024)
15:17:47.084544 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud_client.cpp:96        | _qemud_pipe_send: len= 25 'qemu.timezone=Europe/Oslo'
15:17:47.084554 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud.cpp:273              | _qemudPipe_recvBuffers: -> 29 (of 1024)
15:17:47.084564 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud_client.cpp:96        | _qemud_pipe_send: len=  1 '\x00'
15:17:47.084576 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud.cpp:273              | _qemudPipe_recvBuffers: -> 5 (of 1024)
15:17:47.093263 281473015048960 DEBUG   android_qemud.cpp:169              | _qemudPipe_closeFromGuest
15:17:47.217262 281473247668992 DEBUG   gps.cpp:52                         | sending '$GPGGA,141747,3914.2353,N,12309.0019,W,1,6,,0.0,M,0.,M,,,*47'
15:17:47.217350 281473247668992 DEBUG   gps.cpp:52                         | sending '$GPRMC,141747,A,3914.2353,N,12309.0019,W,0.00,0.00,301023,0.0,W*47'
15:17:47.597353 281473091595008 INFO    os_utils.cc:86                     | Unable to find netsim ini file: /run/user/1001/netsim.ini
15:17:47.597407 281473091595008 ERROR   packet_streamer_client.cc:116      | Starting netsim since the process died
15:17:47.597463 281473091595008 ERROR   packet_streamer_client.cc:85       | Netsimd launch command:
15:17:47.597486 281473091595008 ERROR   packet_streamer_client.cc:86       | 
15:17:47.603566 281473091595008 ERROR   Command_Posix.cpp:312              | Unable to spawn process  due to:, No such file or directory
15:17:47.603582 281473091595008 ERROR   packet_streamer_client.cc:91       | Running netsimd as pid: -1441528864.
15:17:47.603597 281473091595008 ERROR   packet_streamer_client.cc:120      | Retry connecting to netsim in 4 second.
15:17:47.925377 281473108601600 DEBUG   async-socket-connector.c:201       | Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 111 -> Connection refused
15:17:47.925420 281473108601600 DEBUG   async-socket-connector.c:215       | ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 21
15:17:48.217487 281473247668992 DEBUG   gps.cpp:52                         | sending '$GPGGA,141748,3914.2353,N,12309.0019,W,1,6,,0.0,M,0.,M,,,*47'
15:17:48.217585 281473247668992 DEBUG   gps.cpp:52                         | sending '$GPRMC,141748,A,3914.2353,N,12309.0019,W,0.00,0.00,301023,0.0,W*47'
Channel list update timeout - try to continue anyway
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Completing interface initialization
Mode: IEEE 802.11g  Channel: 8  Frequency: 2447 MHz
DFS 0 channels required radar detection
RATE[0] rate=10 flags=0x1
RATE[1] rate=20 flags=0x1
RATE[2] rate=55 flags=0x1
RATE[3] rate=110 flags=0x1
hostapd_setup_bss(hapd=0xaaab85ca2000 (wlan1), first=1)
wlan1: Flushing old station entries
wlan1: Deauthenticate all stations
Using interface wlan1 with hwaddr 00:13:10:85:fe:01 and ssid "AndroidWifi"
wlan1: Event TX_STATUS (16) received
unknown mgmt cb frame subtype 8
wlan1: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->ENABLED
wlan1: AP-ENABLED 
wlan1: Setup of interface done.
15:17:49.217694 281473247668992 DEBUG   gps.cpp:52                         | sending '$GPGGA,141749,3914.2353,N,12309.0019,W,1,6,,0.0,M,0.,M,,,*47'
15:17:49.217755 281473247668992 DEBUG   gps.cpp:52                         | sending '$GPRMC,141749,A,3914.2353,N,12309.0019,W,0.00,0.00,301023,0.0,W*47'
15:17:49.925304 281473108601600 DEBUG   PerfStatReporter.cpp:180           | MemoryReport: uptime: 6064, Res/ResMax/Virt/VirtMax: 753418240 753418240 3591929856 3591929856
15:17:50.217850 281473247668992 DEBUG   gps.cpp:52                         | sending '$GPGGA,141750,3914.2353,N,12309.0019,W,1,6,,0.0,M,0.,M,,,*47'
15:17:50.217911 281473247668992 DEBUG   gps.cpp:52                         | sending '$GPRMC,141750,A,3914.2353,N,12309.0019,W,0.00,0.00,301023,0.0,W*47'
15:17:50.341276 281473032055552 DEBUG   android_qemud_service.cpp:81       | qemud_service_connect_client: registered client channel -1 for 'sensors' service
15:17:50.346676 281473032055552 DEBUG   android_qemud.cpp:194              | _qemudPipe_sendBuffers: 000f
15:17:50.346750 281473032055552 DEBUG   android_qemud.cpp:194              | _qemudPipe_sendBuffers: time:5233539877
15:17:50.346764 281473032055552 DEBUG   hw-sensors.cpp:436                 | _hwSensorClient_receive: 'time:5233539877'
15:17:50.346800 281473032055552 DEBUG   android_qemud.cpp:194              | _qemudPipe_sendBuffers: 000c
15:17:50.346831 281473032055552 DEBUG   android_qemud.cpp:194              | _qemudPipe_sendBuffers: list-sensors
15:17:50.346843 281473032055552 DEBUG   hw-sensors.cpp:436                 | _hwSensorClient_receive: 'list-sensors'
15:17:50.346848 281473032055552 DEBUG   hw-sensors.cpp:284                 | _hwSensorClient_send: '133119'
15:17:50.346858 281473032055552 DEBUG   android_qemud_client.cpp:96        | _qemud_pipe_send: len=  6 '133119'
15:17:50.346868 281473032055552 DEBUG   android_qemud.cpp:273              | _qemudPipe_recvBuffers: -> 10 (of 1024)
15:17:50.493402 281473023552256 ERROR   CrashReporter.cpp:225              | crashhandler_die: fatal: kvm_user_backed_ram_map: error registering slot: Invalid argument
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Is there something I am missing in the setup of my environment or how I am building the emulator tool that would cause this? The avd was made using the avdmanager and a system image downloaded with the skdmanager tool so I think this would not be the problem.

Finally here is the result of lscpu in case they are relevant:

```
Architecture:           aarch64
  CPU op-mode(s):       64-bit
  Byte Order:           Little Endian
CPU(s):                 20
  On-line CPU(s) list:  0-19
Vendor ID:              Apple
  Model name:           Icestorm-M1-Max
    Model:              0
    Thread(s) per core: 1
    Core(s) per socket: 2
    Socket(s):          1
    Stepping:           0x2
    Frequency boost:    enabled
    CPU(s) scaling MHz: 29%
    CPU max MHz:        2064.0000
    CPU min MHz:        600.0000
    BogoMIPS:           48.00
    Flags:              fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 atomics fphp asimdhp cpuid asimdrdm jscvt fcma lrcpc dcpop sha3 asimddp sha512 asimdfhm dit uscat ilrcpc flagm ssbs 
                        sb paca pacg dcpodp flagm2 frint
  Model name:           Firestorm-M1-Max
    Model:              0
    Thread(s) per core: 1
    Core(s) per socket: 8
    Socket(s):          1
    Stepping:           0x2
    CPU(s) scaling MHz: 19%
    CPU max MHz:        3228.0000
    CPU min MHz:        600.0000
    BogoMIPS:           48.00
    Flags:              fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 atomics fphp asimdhp cpuid asimdrdm jscvt fcma lrcpc dcpop sha3 asimddp sha512 asimdfhm dit uscat ilrcpc flagm ssbs 
                        sb paca pacg dcpodp flagm2 frint
  Model name:           Icestorm-M1-Max
    Model:              0
    Thread(s) per core: 1
    Core(s) per socket: 2
    Socket(s):          1
    Stepping:           0x2
    CPU(s) scaling MHz: 29%
    CPU max MHz:        2064.0000
    CPU min MHz:        600.0000
    BogoMIPS:           48.00
    Flags:              fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 atomics fphp asimdhp cpuid asimdrdm jscvt fcma lrcpc dcpop sha3 asimddp sha512 asimdfhm dit uscat ilrcpc flagm ssbs 
                        sb paca pacg dcpodp flagm2 frint
  Model name:           Firestorm-M1-Max
    Model:              0
    Thread(s) per core: 1
    Core(s) per socket: 8
    Socket(s):          1
    Stepping:           0x2
    CPU(s) scaling MHz: 19%
    CPU max MHz:        3228.0000
    CPU min MHz:        600.0000
    BogoMIPS:           48.00
    Flags:              fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 atomics fphp asimdhp cpuid asimdrdm jscvt fcma lrcpc dcpop sha3 asimddp sha512 asimdfhm dit uscat ilrcpc flagm ssbs 
                        sb paca pacg dcpodp flagm2 frint
Caches (sum of all):    
  L1d:                  2.3 MiB (20 instances)
  L1i:                  3.5 MiB (20 instances)
  L2:                   56 MiB (6 instances)
NUMA:                   
  NUMA node(s):         1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):    0-19
Vulnerabilities:        
  Gather data sampling: Not affected
  Itlb multihit:        Not affected
  L1tf:                 Not affected
  Mds:                  Not affected
  Meltdown:             Not affected
  Mmio stale data:      Not affected
  Retbleed:             Not affected
  Spec rstack overflow: Not affected
  Spec store bypass:    Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
  Spectre v1:           Mitigation; __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:           Not affected
  Srbds:                Not affected
  Tsx async abort:      Not affected
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this and I hope someone has an answer!